# React Native - ListView

Tags: react, react-native

O ListView do ReactNative aceita um array de arrays ?
Pois preciso receber os dados da API da seguinte forma :

```
[[{"userId":1,"userName":"Ricardo"},{"userId":1,"userName":"Ricardo"}],[{"userId":1,"userName":"Ricardo"},{"userId":1,"userName":"Ricardo"}]].
```

Fiz o seguinte código para exibi-lo :

```js
renderRowUsers(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
     return rowData.map(function(user, i){
        return(
          <View key={i}>
            <Text>{user.userId}</Text>
            <View>
              <Text>{user.userName}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
    });
}
```

e

```js
const usersDS = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.user !== r2.user
});

this.state = {
    usersDataSource: usersDS.cloneWithRows([{
        "userId": "",
        "userName": "Ricardo"
    }])
}
```

```js
<ListView 
    style={{paddingTop: 2, height:100}}
    dataSource={this.state.usersDataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRowUsers.bind(this)}
/>
```

Mas isso me retorna o seguinte erro :

> "StaticRender.reder():A valid React element(or null) must be retorned. You may 
>   have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

Comment: Podes mostrar o código de `ListView`? dá-me ideia que essa array de `this.renderRowUsers` devia ir para dentro do jsx de `ListView`

Comment: Acrescentei no código, fiquei na dúvida do que colocar no rowHasChanged , pois como ele vai comparar os arrays ?

Comment: Era melhor colocares o(s) teu(s) component completo, assim pedaços dele é dificil saber como é a lógica.

Answer (score 1):

Concordo que você deve por os components em completo. Só com o que você tém agora aqui não dá para a gente saber o que está acontecendo.

Verifique a existência da função render() de cada component, porquê é necessária para cada um. A sua resposta da API parece ser simples, nada demais. Se for só uma array dentro de outra, eu só faria isso: usaria resposta[0] para pegar a array de objetos e fazia um map pra criar Item components baseado em cada objeto.

Não sei o contexto que você pôs **this.state**, mas você não pode mudar o state só fazendo um reassignment da variável state. É contra **immutability** da variável, que é um dos princípios do React. Quando você quiser mudar o state, você usa `this.setState({ chave1: valor1, chave2: valor2 })`, por exemplo, para definir um novo estado pros valores incluidos. O unico local que voce pode definir o state usando this.state = {} é na função **constructor** se você estiver usando **ES6** (se não, defina o estado initial usando função **getInitialState()**, retornando um objeto literal com chave-valores dela).